# Momentum carrying fields

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, momentum, field-theory

Through some of my recent questions I have come to know of fields as an agent which can act as momentum. What is the correct physical picture that I should derive from statements like this? Where exactly is this momentum stored and how is it distributed in these fields? Do the electric and magnetic fields carry momentum separately? How is the relative arrangement of energy distributed over the field and the momentum distributed over the field? I have also got to learn and it's pretty obvious that fields can carry angular momentum as well. Is the distribution of angular momentum any different than the distribution of linear momentum and how to take into account the variation of angular momentum with respect to different reference points?

Comment: Fields change. As they change, they communicate these changes to the rest of the field. They can do this many ways, but I'm simplifying it to call that a wavefront. The movement of a wavefront shows net movement of energy. Energy is directly translatable to momentum. Therefore, the momentum of fields is held in their communications of changes to the field.... I just realized that wasn't nearly as well explained as what's in my head

Comment: @Jimnosperm : Why choose momentum ? Why can't we keep it as simple as energy only . Why do we need the field to have momentum ?

Comment: In the article on the [Poynting Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector#Static_fields), there's an example of static fields with angular momentum. Also think about light. In classic EM, light is just an E field transverse to a B field and it has a definite energy and momentum.

Comment: @AgniveshSingh saying it translates energy is equivalent to saying it has momentum. Momentum is a form of energy but more specific to movement of information. Short answer: that's the same thing but "momentum" is more descriptive

Comment: @Jimnosperm : Momentum , given by background of classical physics , is the quantity of motion possessed by an object ,it can relate to kinetic energy . As I can visualize what you mean by momentum of a field is a quantity which related to the change in energy of field ,E1, by a relation which resembles the relation between kinetic energy and momentum namely , (2*E1*K) where K is some constant . Am I right ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh I don't know quite what you are trying to say. But if the field is massless, then the momentum is equivalent to the energy carried by a wavefront $p=E/c$

Comment: @Jimnosperm : What I am trying to say is that the Newtonian notion associates momentum with objects having mass and When you define a new quantity to be momentum it is analogous to defining the rate of change of electric flux as a form of electric current called displacement current . Isn't it so ?

Comment: Both carry energy seperately. However the momentum is a joint qauntity and cannot be seperated.

Answer (score 4):

To make sense out of this first consider stationary fields (like electrostatics, magnetostatics, etc...). We don't say such fields "store" momentum, that is bad language.

Instead static fields have energy density distributed over space, so that for example for the electric field we have the energy density $du(\vec{x}) \propto \vec{E}^2(\vec{x})$ and similarity for magneto static field.

Now when the field varies with time, energy density starts to change at spacial positions, but conservation of energy says that this change in energy has to flow to nearby positions. This "flow" of energy is the momentum carried out by time varying fields.

Notice that the same idea applies even for Quantum Fields. where particle excitations represent wave-like excitations of these fields, the static underlying field also has a uniform energy density but that is neglected as being zero point energy (if we ignore gravity).

Comment: How can you equate flow of momentum with transfer of energy ? They both are different physical quantities.And even I have read statements like a static field does have linear momentum too ..

Comment: Physical laws always relate different physical quantities (however through dimensionful parameters). In the case of E&M, the change (temporal) in energy density is proportional to the divergence of the poynting vector which is identified as the "momentum of the EM field"

Comment: Moreover, Special relativity teaches us that actually Energy and momentum are part of one object called the Energy-momentum four-vector. But again even non-relativistically, you can always find such relations, for example the Navier-Stokes energy conservation equation for non-relativistic hydrodynamics